# searching on List (integer) field for values greater than than selection (drupal 7)

Tags: search, views

i'm working on a site for a real estate company which involves a search form.

i've got a view set up called search results and have set an exposed form (form in block) with a field to search Number of Bedrooms.

Its set up in content type as 
Search Number of Bedrooms   field_search_number_of_bedrooms List (integer)  Check boxes/radio buttons

with the following content

Content:                                                                          1|1 Bedroom
2|2 Bedrooms
3|3 Bedrooms
4|4 Bedrooms
5|5 Bedrooms
6|More than 5 Bedrooms

in my search filter i get the following 
Is one of
Is all of
Is none of
Is empty (NULL)
Is not empty (NOT NULL)

whereas i'm looking for the same filters that you'd get for an integer field.

is there a better way of allowing the editor to assign a number of bedrooms in the content type using a select list (so i can store the integer but display the label in both the admin and the exposed form)?

Comment: I am struggling a similar trouble at the moment. I would also need to filtering of values according to the key of list (integer). Have you found a solution for this particular problem?